# How to update the arrow style and shrink parameter of an existing annotation in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to change the appearance of an already existing annotation, especially the properties of its arrow.
Although I figured out how to change many of its properties, unexpectedly I could not figure out how to properly change the arrow style and the shrink parameters.

I know that the arrow of an annotation is defined in the 'arrow_patch' attribute of the 'Annotation' object. 'arrow_patch' is a 'FancyArrowPatch' object, therefore, I expect that its properties can be set accordingly (i.e. by using the method 'set_arrowstyle'). Apparently other parameters of the arrow can be indeed changed e.g. the connection style by 'set_connectionstyle'.

Here is a code which demonstrates that the style of a stand-alone 'FancyArrowPatch' can be changed, but the arrow of an annotation not:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

arrow = FancyArrowPatch((0.1, 0.1), (.9, .9),
                                 mutation_scale=100)
ca = ax.add_patch(arrow)
print(id(arrow), id(ca))
arrow.set(ec='red') # works
arrow.set_arrowstyle('->') # works
arrow.set_connectionstyle('Arc3,rad=.2') # works

ann = ax.annotate('Annotation', xy=(.1, .9), xytext=(.9, .1), arrowprops=dict(fc='black'))
ann.arrow_patch.set_arrowstyle('->') # does not work
ann.arrow_patch.set_connectionstyle('Arc3,rad=.2') # works
ann.arrow_patch.set(ec='red') # works
plt.show()
```

So my question: is there anything what I forgot to get the annotation arrow style updated?
Actually, I tried calling the 'update_positions' method of the 'Annotation' object without success.

I am using python 3.11 and matplotlib 3.7.1.